# Can anyone point me a very good recent magento extension development tutorial?

Tags: magento-1.7

I downloaded  magento 1.7.0.2. I was surfing for the past week and testing tutorials on the net and found that most of them is so confusing. For example... They had a path that tells where to put your layout page then when I look at the magento in ftp, the structure is very different from what they are explaining.

Most of the tutorials I found are more than a year old and are probably not compatible with the latest version. That's why I'm looking for the most recent tutorial I could find.

I hope there is a tutorial similar to phpfox knowledge base. Only a few chapters and few examples but covers everything you need to know in creating modules...

If someone could point me to, i would be greatly appreciated...

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

don't have a link, but as 1.7.0.2 has been out for almost a year, so you could expect it to be the case.

Whilst it's aimed at 'design/layout', I would also suggest going through the [designer guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide). It's a painful read, but it help me a great deal to understand Magento methodology and where things are 'meant' to be in file structure. It may just help you to find tut references as sometime things in the 'less than best' location still works.

depending on your extension type [their wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/All%20Categories?idx=5_-_modules_and_development:0_-_module_development_in_magento) may have a few nuggets.

Answer (score 1):

Hay did you read magento developer part 1 to 8? If not link is **[HERE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento)**

That a pretty good example and explanation (basic to advanced).

Comment: yup, i read it already but all i can find there is how the core extensions work. I was hoping i could find any tutorial that explains creating third party extensions that does not require editing the core of magento.